# Facebook4j: Get feed from user excluding posts by other users

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, filter, facebook4j

I'm trying to fetch the latest posts of a few users using a batch request:

```
new BatchRequest(RequestMethod.GET, USERID/feed?limit=5&fields=from,created_time,message")
```

The problem is that it does not only return posts done by this user, but also posts posted to his timeline by others. As this person is quite popular, these are a lot.

The following works

```
if(post.getFrom().getId() == USERID)
```

but is more of a workaround than a real solve of this problem. Is there a better approach to only get posts done by this user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself:

I made the wrong assumption that I dealt with a user, not a page. 
The correct batch response to get only posts made by the page simply is:

```
new BatchRequest(RequestMethod.GET, PAGENAME/posts?limit=5&fields=from,created_time,message")
```